# Queuable chaining not working- First queueble doing webserivce call , second queueable should wait till result of first came

Tags: apex, webservices, rest, queueable-apex

We have one use case we have to rely on external system to fetch the data and then only real time we can update the records in salesforce using values returned from webservice.

we tried chaining using queueable unfortunately it's still not waiting for the result to come from first service and firing next step.

Is there any way we can have system wait till the result come and then only it use the values return in response and perform dml in salesforce.

```
public class chainingjob implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts  {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // Webservice code goes here  go against external system and get response     

        // Chain this job to next job by submitting the next job, this job will use response come in first job.
        System.enqueueJob(new SecondJob());
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Chaining a queueable should work with your use case, can you please share some snippet for us to analyze why chaining failed in your scenario.

Comment: Are you literally chaining, or are you simply enqueuing both at the same time? You need to [edit] the question to add some code snippets.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW . Can you please tell me aren't enqueuing and chaining same.  I wonder as per documentation first job can enque another in execute method. wouldn't that make the second job run only when first complete. Please help.

Comment: Thanks @NagendraSingh

Comment: Chaining means enqueuing the next queueable at the end of execution of the first queueable. Simply enqueueuing both at the same time is not chaining.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW.. So as per below code public class AsyncExecutionExample implements Queueable {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // Your processing logic here       

        // Chain this job to next job by submitting the next job
        System.enqueueJob(new SecondJob());
    }
}  ..Wouldn't second will only starts when first complete. In our case First job is webservice call and second is dependent on first job results. Since we want to use response return from first job to be passed in second job. But unfortuntely salesforce is not behaving that way.

Comment: Just [edit] the question to add the code snippets (look at the editing help to know how to format it).

Comment: And show how you are trying to get the response to send to the second queueable.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. Please see I have added code snippet

Comment: Please show how you do the Web service call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain chaining with some examples.
In your case you should be calling your webservice in place of //Do Some Logic, and after that you can execute `System.enqueueJob` again to execute you next job with the result from webservice.

```
public without sharing class ExampleChainingQueueableJobs implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    public void execute(QueueableContext param1) {
        
        // Do some logic
        
        // Here if you call the same class again it will be called self chaining. 
        // This will infinitely chain this class, so use it very wisely or with proper conditions
        
        // If you replace this `ExampleChainingQueueableJobs` with some other class, then it be called chaining with other queueable class
        // But no matter what this below code will only execute when above all logics have run without any issues.
        System.enqueueJob(new ExampleChainingQueueableJobs());
    
    }
}
```

For eg:

```
public without sharing class ExampleChainingQueueableJobs implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    public void execute(QueueableContext param1) {

        Http http = new Http();

        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
        httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);
        System.enqueueJob(new ExampleChainingQueueableChainJob(httpResponse.getBody()));

    }

}
```

---

```
public with sharing class ExampleChainingQueueableChainJob implements Queueable{

    public String dataFromPriorJob;

    public ExampleChainingQueueableChainJob(String dataFromPriorJob){
        this.dataFromPriorJob = dataFromPriorJob;

    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext param1) {

        System.debug(dataFromPriorJob);

    }
}
```